# what's the antonym for catchError in rjxs?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have the following code in my interceptor.

```
return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
            catchError( (error):any =>  {
                console.log(error);
                this.loaderService.storeLoaderOff();
            }), tap( (success)=>{
                console.log(success);
               this.loaderService.storeLoaderOff();
            })
        );
```

but I also need onSuccess pipe so that if it returns success, i do something else.

I couldn't find anything like that. Maybe you guys had experience with it.

Comment: You can use `tap` maybe.

Comment: it works. so in tap pipe, it will trigger when http returns success and not error , right?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of it. So I'm just googling it.

Comment: Yes tap is the way to go!

Comment: I tried, it but even though API returns error, it still goes into tap pipe

Comment: I think this page will help you: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html

Comment: Thanks guys. just a little bit of more help and I'd so appreciate that. I updated my question. take a look. basically on error and on success i need to turn of the loader. turns out when there's an error, it goes to catchError pipe and it also goes to tap anyway.

Comment: Again I'm not sure, but I think you can use `tap` with 3 callbacks (arguments) instead of `catchError`. First callback is `whatever`, second callback is `error` and third callback is `complete`

Comment: I made it work as you said. Thanks so much

Comment: Glad to hear it worked :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Tap lets you listen in and takes a success handler followed by an optional error handler

```js
const { throwError, of } = rxjs;
const { tap } = rxjs.operators;

throwError('This is the error').pipe(
  tap(
    res => { console.log(res); },
    err => { console.log(err); }
  )
).subscribe(_ => {}, _ => {});

of('This is the response').pipe(
  tap(
    res => { console.log(res); },
    err => { console.log(err); }
  )
).subscribe(_ => {}, _ => {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```